# URL request emulating curl --data-binary

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I want to send a URL request equivalent to using to json objects in the post data, separated by newline.
This is for indexing two items in bulk for Elasticsearch.

This works fine:

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/myindex/mydoc?pretty=true' --data-binary @myfile.json
```

where myfile.json:

```
{"index": {"_parent": "btaCovzjQhqrP4s3iPjZKQ"}}    
{"title": "hello"}
{"index": {"_parent": "btaCovzjQhqrP4s3iPjZKQ"}}
{"title": "world"}
```

When I try it using:

```
req = urllib2.Request(url,data=
json.dumps({"index": {"_parent": "btaCovzjQhqrP4s3iPjZKQ"}}) + "\n" +
json.dumps({"title":"hello"}) + "\n" + 
json.dumps({"index": {"_parent": "btaCovzjQhqrP4s3iPjZKQ"}}) + "\n" +
json.dumps({"title":"world"})
```

I get:

```
HTTP Error 500: Internal Server Error
```

Comment: Yes I did, I get a HTTP Error 500: Internal Server Error response

Comment: The usecase for me is actually a bulk_index request for ElasticSearch. I tried to simplify the example. Edited above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "HTTP Error 500" may be from forgetting to include an index name or index type.

Also: for bulk inserts, elasticsearch requires a trailing "\n" character after the last record, or it won't insert that record.

Try:

```
import urllib2
import json

url = 'http://localhost:9200/myindex/mydoc/_bulk?pretty=true'

data = json.dumps({"index": {"_parent": "btaCovzjQhqrP4s3iPjZKQ"}}) + "\n" + json.dumps({"title":"hello"}) + "\n" + json.dumps({"index": {"_parent": "btaCovzjQhqrP4s3iPjZKQ"}}) + "\n" + json.dumps({"title":"world"})

req = urllib2.Request(url,data=data+"\n")

f = urllib2.urlopen(req)
print f.read()
```

Or, with some refactoring:

```
import urllib2
import json

url = 'http://localhost:9200/myindex/mydoc/_bulk?pretty=true'

data = [
    {"index": {"_parent": "btaCovzjQhqrP4s3iPjZKQ"}},
    {"title":"hello"},
    {"index": {"_parent": "btaCovzjQhqrP4s3iPjZKQ"}},
    {"title":"world"}
]

encoded_data = "\n".join(map(json.dumps,data)) + "\n"

req = urllib2.Request(url,data=encoded_data)

f = urllib2.urlopen(req)
print f.read()
```

Answer (score 2):

> The usecase for me is actually a bulk_index request for ElasticSearch.

This is made a lot easier with [`rawes`](https://github.com/humangeo/rawes):

```
import rawes
es = rawes.Elastic('localhost:9200')

with open('myfile.json') as f:
   lines = f.readlines()

es.post('someindex/sometype/_bulk', data=lines)
```

Comment: Thanks, very interesting!
But I am trying to write this myself, and do not want to rely on outside ES packages, just to emulate the curl command capabilities.
Any way to accomplish this simply with a python requests call?